# How to meter pixel on screen

Tags: pixel

I need to meter pixel on web page or on the screen. I used orange pixel meter is any other program similar to mater pixel on screen.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please be more specific?

Comment: it seems that "orange pixel meter" is one of those screen pixel ruler programs; but which platform do you need one on?

Comment: What do you want to measure, exactly? Arbitrary points or DOM tree elements? If it's the latter, use Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Check this addon for Firefox/Chrome/Safari: http://www.kevinfreitas.net/extensions/measureit/

Comment: As reported on Chrome store - full of adware, avoid this solution!

Comment: Bear in mind that my answer was posted *over three years ago*. Back then MeasureIt had no adware. As of Dec 8, 2010, my answer was perfectly valid. Instead of a downvote, I'd restrain myself to just leaving a comment an perhaps adding a note to the answer itself. I cannot be held responsible for what the developers of a given piece of software do with it in the future, you know.

Comment: You are correct, I did add a note now and will withdraw the down vote when the edit goes through (since I can't do it at the time unless the answer is edited)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what you mean but if you want to get the RGB value of a pixel at a particular coordinate, you can use this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
import sys
import gtk

def get_pixel_rgb(x, y):
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, 1, 1)
    pixbuf.get_from_drawable(gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window(),
                             gtk.gdk.colormap_get_system(), 
                             x, y, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    return pixbuf.get_pixels_array()[0][0]

print get_pixel_rgb(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

[via @htorque](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16620/is-there-a-command-line-tool-which-returns-the-colour-of-the-pixel-based-on-scree/16622#16622)